# Instagram API: Instagram gallery is no longer working

Tags: web-applications, instagram-api

I am using the instagram API to fetch all instagram images based on a hashtag. This is no longer working. I am aware that Instagram have recently made an update to their API, where to use the API it must first pass a review process. However, since gallery is on a one off project, a web site, I am wondering if we do not qualify to use the API since during submission Instagram shows an error message where the public_content api call is not available.

Can somebody confirm that this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Third-party websites that enabled users to search Instagram photos and hashtags, such as Gramfeed and Mixagram, also ceased functioning on June 1. 
You can read the new Instagram Platform Policy [here](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/)

Answer (score 0):

As @jbassx said, Instagram has changed their Platform Policy, and none of the third-party apps (such as yours) will work until you've applied to get out of "sandbox" mode. Head over to the [Instagram developer area](https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/) to manage your apps.

There is no workaround, short of scraping the website. Which is so much harder, more impractical and less polite than just jumping through the new hoops Instagram has set up.

The review/approval process takes about a week, according to [this post](http://developers.instagram.com/post/145262544121/instagram-platform-update-effective-june-1-2016).